# How to Convert a tab delimited file with commas in values to .CSV and the values with commas to be enclosed in double quotes?

Tags: linux, sed, awk, csv

I have a **.CSV** file (Lets say tab_delimited_file.csv) that I download from a web portal of a particular vendor. When I moved the file to one of my Linux directories, I noticed that this particular **.CSV** file is actually a **tab delimited** file which is named as **.CSV**. Please find below few sample records of the file.

```
"""column1"""   """column2"""   """column3"""   """column4"""   """column5"""   """column6"""   """column7"""  
12  455 string with quotes, and with a comma in between 4432    6787    890 88  
4432    6787    another, string with quotes, and with two comma in between  890 88  12  455  
11  22  simple string   77  777 333 22
```

The above sample records are separated by `tabs`. I know the header of the file is very weird but this is the way I received the file format to be.

I tried to use **`tr`** command to replace the `tabs` with `commas` but the file gets messed up completely due to the extra commas in the record values. I need the record values with commas in them to be enclosed in double quotes. The command I used is as below.

```
tr '\t' ',' < tab_delimited_file.csv > comma_separated_file.csv
```

This converts the file into the below format.

```
"""column1""","""column2""","""column3""","""column4""","""column5""","""column6""","""column7"""
12,455,string with quotes, and with a comma in between,4432,6787,890,88
4432,6787,another, string with quotes, and with two comma in between,890,88,12,455
11,22,simple string,77,777,333,22
```

I need help to convert the sample file into the below format.

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7
12,455,"string with quotes, and with a comma in between",4432,6787,890,88
4432,6787,"another, string with quotes, and with two comma in between",890,88,12,455
11,22,"simple string",77,777,333,22
```

Any solution in either using **`sed`** or **`awk`** will be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will produce the output you asked for, but it's not clear if the criteria I'm assuming to be true for which fields to put in quotes (any containing a comma or a space), for example, is actually what you want so test it yourself with other input to see:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
  {
     gsub(/"/,"")
     for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
         if ($i ~ /[,[:space:]]/)
             $i = "\"" $i "\""
     gsub(OFS,",")
     print
  }
  ' file
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7
12,455,"string with quotes, and with a comma in between",4432,6787,890,88
4432,6787,"another, string with quotes, and with two comma in between",890,88,12,455
11,22,"simple string",77,777,333,22
```

Comment: I know it's been ages you provided solution to this problem of mine, and I am sorry to bug you again for it now...  I have to use this code again, so if possible, could you please explain to help me understand what the above code does? It will be very helpful... Thanks...

Comment: I used your answer, and I +1d it too... I did not know how to use SO in the beginning, so did not accept the answer... :(

Answer (score 1):

One way using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = "\t"; OFS = "," }
    FNR == 1 {
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { gsub( /"+/, "", $i ) }
        print $0
        next
    }
    FNR > 1 {   
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
            w = split( $i, _, " " )
            if ( w > 1 ) { $i = "\"" $i "\"" }
        }
        print $0
    }
' infile
```

It uses a tab to split fields in input and a comma to write in output. For the header is easy, simple remove all double quotes. For data lines, for each field split with spaces and surround with double quotes only if the split returned more than one field.

It yields:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7  
12,455,"string with quotes, and with a comma in between",4432,6787,890,88  
4432,6787,"another, string with quotes, and with two comma in between",890,88,12,455  
11,22,"simple string",77,777,333,22
```

Comment: You don't need to test for `FNR > 1` since that condition must be true for you to reach that line. You can test if a string contains a blank char by using `if ($i ~ / /)` instead of `w = split( $i, _, " " ); if ( w > 1 )`. You can just say `print` instead of `print $0`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thank you. You are right. Those changes are fine, but would transform my solution in yours so I will leave it as is.